# Passing awk results to command after pipe

Tags: bash, awk, find, xattr

I'm trying to pass what would be the `awk` outputs of `print $1` and `print $2` to `setfattr` after a pipe. The value of the extended attribute is an MD5 hash which is calculated from input files from the output of a `find` command. This is what I have so far:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f \
  -regextype posix-extended \
  -not -iregex '.*\.(jpg|docx|psd|jpeg|png|html|bmp|gif|txt|pdf|mp3|bts|srt)' \
| parallel -j 64 md5sum | awk '{system("setfattr -n user.digest.md5 -v " $1 $2)}'
```

Having `awk '{print $1}'` and `$2` after the last pipe returns the hash and file path respectively just fine, I'm just not sure how to get those values into `setfattr`. `setfattr` just throws a generic usage error when that command is run. Is this just a syntax issue or am I going about this totally wrong?

Comment: perhaps try `for` loop. Like `for atr1 in $(find ....) ;do setfatter ....$atr ;done`

Comment: yeah something like ```for i in find /path/to/dir -type f -regextype posix-extended -not -iregex '.*\.(jpg|docx|psd|jpeg|png|html|bmp|gif|txt|pdf|mp3|bts|srt)' -print0); do setfattr -n user.digest.md5 -v "$(md5sum "${i}")" ${i}; done``` does work, but I'm not sure how to make it work with ```parallel```.

Comment: `( your entire for loop ) | parallel -j 64 md5sum` , may be this work.

Comment: I decided to go with a while loop and ```md5deep```. It's not great, but it seems to run a little faster that single-threaded ```md5sum```:  ```find /path/to/dir -type f -regextype posix-extended -not -iregex '.*\.(jpg|docx|psd|jpeg|png|html|bmp|gif|txt|pdf|mp3|bts|srt)' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do setfattr -n user.digest.md5 -v "$(md5deep -j 8 "${i}" | awk '{print $1}')" "${i}"; done```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try piping the output of the parallel command into a while loop:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f \
    -regextype posix-extended \
    -not -iregex '.*\.(jpg|docx|psd|jpeg|png|html|bmp|gif|txt|pdf|mp3|bts|srt)' |
  parallel -j 64 md5sum |
  while read hash file; do
    setfattr -n user.digest.md5 -v ${hash} ${file}
  done
```

Comment: This has the benefit of using the `parallel` command and uses one fewer child process.

Comment: Yes indeed that does work. I guess I had no idea that ```while read arg1 arg2``` would work sort-of like ```awk '{print $arg1, $arg2}'``` works. Thanks very much.

Comment: When you put bash built-in commands in a pipeline, they are executed in a sub-shell, and get the same file descriptor treatment as any other command in the pipeline.